# Splash screen + Main window

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have a C# application which runs into trouble when it comes to multi-threads / backgroundworkers when I'm using a splash screen before I load the main window.

my code look something like this:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{

.. do some stuff

ShowSplash(); // where i show a splash screen and load some stuff

...
```

As the last step of `ShowSplash`, I do the following:

```
new MyCabApplication<MyMainWorkItem, MDIParentForm>().Run(); -- where i load the form through cab.
```

The problem is that when I do that I get the following exception:

Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead

Any idea what can I do?

Here is my showsplash function:

```
 private static DialogResult ShowSplash(AutoResetEvent controller)
 {
     // create and register splash screen
     splashScreen = new PointSplashScreen();
     Application.Run(splashScreen);
     return DialogResult.OK;
 }
```

Comment: Include the threading and background workers code in your example.

Comment: Follow the advice in the exception message.

Comment: Since the problem occurs when showing the splash screen, you should post the implementation of `ShowSplash()` so we can get a better understanding on how it ends up starting a second message loop.

Comment: see my splash implementation in the original post(Edited)

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

1. Instead of using `Application.Run`, just create a new instance of the form and then call `ShowDialog`.  Move `new MyCabApplication<MyMainWorkItem, MDIParentForm>().Run();` outside of the Splash Screen after the call to `ShowDialog()`.  You can check properties of the Splash screen if this code should not always be run.
2. Instead of using `Application.Run(Form)`, use [`Application.Run(ApplicationContext)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901(VS.80).aspx).  You will need to create a new `ApplicationContext` and move your code there.

Solution 1 is easier.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `MyCabApplication` extends [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y6135ed.aspx). The [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx) method starts a WinForm application by starting a message loop that handles window messages.

Because you are already showing UI, there is already a message loop running, so you cannot start another. To get your main form to show up, make a new instance of it and call `Show()`:

```
var form = new MainForm();
form.Show();
```

Comment: what you mean? but that what the CAB does at the end with MDIParentForm()